# Summary() function splits factor levels when there are only two contrast-coded levels

Tags: r, lme4, summary

I am running a mixed-effects model in R usuing lme4/lmerTest. My model has the following formula:

```
model1 = lmer(DV ~ FactorA + FactorB + Continuous IV 1 + Continuous IV 2 + 
FactorA:FactorB + FactorB:FactorB:Continuous IV 1:Continuous IV 2 + (1 + FactorA|Participant)
```

Factor A and Factor B have two levels each and are contrast coded using the `contr.sum()` function.

When I call the summary of the model, it returns this:

```
summary(model1)
```

```
Fixed Effect                                                 B              SE       t  ....                                       
FactorA1
FactorB1                                                  (Imagine values are reported here as usual)
Cont. IV1
Cont. IV2
FactorA1:FactorB1
FactorAlevel1:FactorBlevel1:Cont. IV 1:Cont. IV2
FactorAlevel1:FactorBlevel2:Cont. IV 1:Cont. IV2
FactorAlevel2:FactorBlevel1:Cont. IV 1:Cont. IV2
FactorAlevel2:FactorBlevel2:Cont. IV 1:Cont. IV2
```

When I run the full-factorial model, it returns the output not split by levels of the factors, similar to the ANOVA table:

```
Full_Factorial = lmer(DV ~ FactorA * FactorB * Continuous IV 1 * Continuous IV 2 +
 (1 + FactorA|Participant)
```

```
summary(Full_Factorial)
```

```
Fixed Effect                                                 B              SE       t  ....                                       
FactorA1
FactorB1                                                  (Imagine values are reported here as usual)
Cont. IV1
Cont. IV2
FactorA1:FactorB1
Cont. IV1:FactorA1
.....
FactorA1:FactorB1:Cont. IV 1:Cont. IV2
```

My question is this: Why in the full-factorial model is the output allowed to determine the effect of the factors within their contrast-coded format, but in the model where I specify specific terms it gives me separate values for each of the factor levels in the higher-order interactions with continuous IVs? Is there a way to force B/SE/t values across levels of the factors for the higher-order interactions for a model like model 1?

This would not be a huge issue for me if I was not worried about reporting semipartial R2 for the effect of `FactorA:FactorB:Cont. IV1:Cont. IV2`; I realize generating the ANOVA table using `anova(model1)` would give me what I'm after for the output itself, but using the `r2beta` function in the `r2glmm` package to determine the semipartial R2's also breaks up the factor levels in model 1. If it is not possible to force the `summary()` function to report the fixed effects in the way I want, does anyone know of a way to generate semipartial R2 for the effects in model1 collapsed across factor levels as in the ANOVA table?

Comment: FWIW this is not a question that's specific to `lme4`. `lme4` uses standard R machinery, namely `model.matrix()`, to translate the fixed-effects part of the model formula into a model matrix (implicitly, this is deciding how the formula defines a particular parameterization of the model). I don't have time to look at this now, but you should be aware that at least the first part of your question is a general question about R's implementation of Wilkinson-Rogers notation